# Moving Divs with the same class

Tags: jquery

Here is my JSFIDDLE [**CLICK HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/sB28J/)

My problem is that I Have classes that are the same that I want to move above a div class. So if your looking at my HTML you will notice that I have the class = catalogItemFooter. I want to move said class before class = catalogThumbnailArea. My issue is, there are multiple classes that share the same class. If you are looking at my fiddle you will notice that it moves both items above the other. I dont want this, I want the name to go above its coresponding catalogThumbnailArea and not add it to all the other ones.

My script so far

```
    $(".catalogItemFooter").parent().insertBefore("table.catalogThumbnailArea");
```

I realize that this may be complex, if you need more info please ask. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("div.catalogItemFooter").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $thumb = $this.closest('table').prevAll('table.catalogThumbnailArea')
                                                                        .first();
    $this.insertBefore($thumb);
});
```

​

I am looping over all the div with the corresponding class and inserting it to the corresponding table.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/sB28J/4/)**

Comment: Its working, now I am just trying to figure out how you came up with that. It looks like you used closest to lock in on the table my only confusion is why the var?? Thank you by the way, just want to understand this.

Comment: ok now I see it, the var $thumb is looking for the table, this is just this (catalogitemfooter) then combined together the insertbefore places the thumb into this... Clever.. Very nice thank you!

Comment: I am just caching the current selector so that we don't query the DOM again... It is always a better idea to cache the selectors if you tend to reuse them again..  You are welcome :)